# Multiples Formularios de contacto en la misma página

Tags: wordpress, formularios, contact-form-7

Tengo la siguiente duda, en una página que estoy haciendo con wordpress mi idea es que en el apartado de contacto, poner unos radiobuttons para poder escojer que formulario de contacto debe utilizar el usuario.
He realizado los diferentes formularios con contact form 7, pero ahora no se me ocurre sin tener que meter codigo, el poder escojer un formulario o otro.
¿ A alguién se le ocurre algo ?
Gracias.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que tienes para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza ACF y creas campos personalizados donde puedes colocar los ids de cada formulario o los shortcodes y luego imprimirlos.

```
<?php
$form = get_field('form');
do_shortcode($form);
```